# Checking a background image that is specified in a class style in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, capybara

Basically I'm doing some automation testing on an interface and I need to check the background of a CSS that is associated with an image. Is there anyway of doing this? I've looked around and haven't seen notes or docs on how you can do this.

Can you use something like page.should have_selector("css element")
I seem to have an issue creating the string it doesn't find the element I'm looking for.

Any help would be great.
Thanks
Ray

Comment: Can this comparison be done by simply accessing the css file name?

Comment: Hey Dru, im not too sure what youre talking about, if you dont mind would you be able to expand on it. Thanks Ray

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using one of the drivers that supports CSS (not rack_test) then you can use the `style` filter to verify an elements CSS styles. Given something like

```
<div class="my_class">....</div>
```

assuming `my_class` sets a background image on the element you could do something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('div.my_class', style: { 'background-image' => 'url_of_the_image' })
```

the url of the image can also be a regexp if you want to match that way (don't care about which host it's coming from, etc.)

```
expect(page).to have_css('div.my_class', style: { 'background-image' => %r{/abc/def.png$} })
```